# Changing Author and Committer details(name and email address) in Eclipse with Egit

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

How can I change the Author and Committer names permanently when committing with Egit using Eclipse Indigo ?

I did a little Googling but I can't find where the Author and Committer names are coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is stored in your user's git configuration (a `.gitconfig` file in your home directory).

In EGit, if you haven't yet set this, a dialog is shown the first time you commit. But you can always change it in the preferences, see here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Identifying_yourself

The configuration is shared with the console Git (C Git).

Comment: Great... I did find the file for setting individual project preferences but not this one. Thanks..

Comment: If HOME is not set to %USERPROFILE% as user level environment variable. Please set that, That resolved my same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows users:**

The `.gitconfig` file is (or, will be )stored in your `HOME` directory, search `environment` in your `start menu` and you can config it.

One problem is that we cannot create such a file beginning with a `.`, if it does not exist. In this case, since we must have installed `git` and we have a programm named `git bash` in our `start menu`, we can create that file with the `git bash`. By default, the `git bash` shares the same `HOME` directory defined among the system environment variables.

So, we can `vi ~/.gitconfig` in the `git bash` command line, and add such codes into it:

```
; user identity
[user]
        name = "Junio C Hamano"
        email = "junkio@twinsun.com"
```

See [this git doc](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html) for details.

Now restart eclipse and the config will work.